# React: Warning setState Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within a render)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Error Message:

> React: Warning setState Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within a render)

This is a react-native app, but I figure, this is more of a react question.

I'm getting the error described in the heading. But I'm puzzled about the reason and I'm not setting state in any of the parent or child components. So I have a grandchild component(CardLayoutResult), which renders a listView and each row renders a new component(Render row) which has a click event, upon clicking it calls a function(onselectLayout) from props(passed from the parent component(Personalization component)(parent function setCardTemplate). This parent function then calls setState of the parent internal state. Then re-rendering occurs.

Why am I getting this error upon click?

**Parent Component**

```
export class Personalization extends Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
   showModel: true,
   editorState: {}
 };

  this.setCardTemplate = this.setCardTemplate.bind(this);
}

setCardTemplate(selectedTemplateObj){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedTemplateObj));
  this.setState({
    showModel: false,
    editorState: selectedTemplateObj
  });
}

render() {
  return (
   <View>
     <CreateCardStep containerState={{showModel:this.state.showModel ,
              editorState: this.state.editorState 
              setCardTemplate:this.setCardTemplate}} />
   </View>
  )
}
```

**Child Component**

```
const CreateCardStep = (_props)  => {
  return (
    <View>
       <CardLayoutResults containerState={_props.containerState} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Grand Child Component**

```
export class CardLayoutResults extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
  render() {

   return(

    <View>
      <ListView
        RenderRow = {(data) => <RenderRow styles={styles} rowObj={data} onSelectLayout={this.props.containerState.setCardTemplate} /> } 
    </View>    
   )
  }
```

**Render Row**

```
 const RenderRow = (props) => {
  let base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,'.concat(props.rowObj.base);

 return (
 <View style={props.styles.templateImage}>
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.onSelectLayout(props.rowObj)}>
     <Image style={props.styles.thumbnail} resizeMode= {Image.resizeMode.contain} source={{uri: base64Image}}/>
   </TouchableHighlight>
 </View>
 );
};
```

**- Update**
This issue seems to be when setting state in the setCardTemplate function

Answer (score 0):

You either need to bind your `setCardTemplate` function in the constructor or call it from a lambda function (binding is better)

```
<View>
      <ListView renderRow = {(data => rowObj={data}} onSelectLayout={() => this.props.containerState.setCardTemplate} />
</View>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I already had this bind. I just edited my post,.

Comment: You `</view>` closing tag is lowercase, should be uppercase in CardLayoutResults component. While RenderRow props should be renderRow.

Comment: Also, onSelectLayout should not be in renderRow props, but standalone props.

Comment: renderRow= {(data) => <RenderRow styles={styles} rowObj={data} onSelectLayout={this.props.containerState.setCardTemplate} />}
                />    no luck. My Parent function setCardTemplate is being called. Without setState(in the setCardTemplate function) it working fine. the issue is when setting state in that function

Answer (score 0):

I guess the renderRow for listView is not called properly

Try

```
<View>
  <ListView
    renderRow = {(data) => <RenderRow rowObj={data} onSelectLayout={this.props.containerState.setCardTemplate} />} 
   />
</View>
```

and pass down the props from personalization component like

```
return (
   <View>
     <CreateCardStep containerState={{showModel:this.state.showModel ,
              editorState: this.state.editorState 
              setCardTemplate:(val) => this.setCardTemplate(val)}} />
   </View>
  )
```

Comment: no luck. I believe it must be something to do with the react rendering lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you are passing props to the child component from the parent.

In this snippet

```
 <CreateCardStep containerState={{showModel:this.state.showModel ,
          editorState: this.state.editorState 
          setCardTemplate:(val) => this.setCardTemplate(val)}} />
```

while passing the function as a prop itself you are calling the function so every time the component render the state will be set which is fine.

But when you click the `Render Row` component state is being set yet for the same property before finishing the render cycle which causes this warning.

To fix it just pass the function from parent as `setCardTemplate: this.setCardTemplate`. It will set the state (and internally will call the render) only on row press, not every time it is rendered